# How to set target for MGSwipeButton in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hello I am using [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) for my `UITableview` in order to swipe my cells. Swiping is working. And I have added these lines in my `CellforRowAtIndex`like below

```
 //configure left buttons
cell.leftButtons = @[[MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"Approve" icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"approveTick"] backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:43.0/255 green:178.0/255 blue:157.0/255 alpha:1.0]]
                     ];

cell.leftSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition3D;


//configure right button
cell.rightButtons=@[[MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"Reject" icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rejectDel"] backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255 green:104.0/255 blue:97.0/255 alpha:1.0]]
                    ];

cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition=MGSwipeTransition3D;
```

Now I want to set target click events for those 2 buttons. But I don't understand properly how to do this. Please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: have you checked my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to listen for button click events you can implement the optional MGSwipeTableCellDelegate, or if you are too lazy to do that, the MGSwipeButton class comes with a convenience block callback ;)

Objective-c

```
[MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"More" backgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] callback:^BOOL(MGSwipeTableCell *sender) {
      NSLog(@"Convenience callback for swipe buttons!");
}]
```

Swift

```
MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor(), callback: {
  (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
      println("Convenience callback for swipe buttons!")
      return true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell *)cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL)fromExpansion {
    NSLog(@"tappedButtonAtIndex: %i",index);
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [Claim_tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"CellindexPath: %i",indexPath);
    return YES;
}
```

this delegate method will call when you click on button Also Don't forgot to add 'MGSwipeTableCellDelegate'

Answer (score 0):

First answer is right with the instructions in [GitHub MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)
But for me is not working with swift 3 so I decided to do it with delegates.

To do in this way is really easy. First I tell to my Class I'm going to implement the MGSwipeTableCell protocol. I do this with an extension:

```
extension ViewController: MGSwipeTableCellDelegate {
    func swipeTableCell(_ cell: MGSwipeTableCell!, tappedButtonAt index: Int, direction: MGSwipeDirection, fromExpansion: Bool) -> Bool {
        print("Button \(index) tapped")
        // here a switch to control the button tapped is a good choice
        return true
    }
}
```

And second: don't forget to set the cell.delate in   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

This is working for me with Xcode 8 and swift 3!

Comment: I have added cell.delegate = self in cellForRowAt in tableview and tried calling this method. this method is not calling in my project. Is there anything else i am missing?